# Multivariate regression in Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, regression

I have been all over Google trying to find a good function/package to perform multivariate regression (i.e. predict multiple continuous variables given another set of multiple continuous variables).

I wish to use something like `fitlm()`, since that also gives me p-value statistics and R squared statistics. Does anything like that exist?

Comment: I am curious, how did this work?  Was `mvregress` a good fit for your purpose? Or some of the other resources mentioned? Or something else altogether?

Comment: I simply decided to execute fitlm() multiple times, since I really needed the p-values which are not present in mvregress

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  It is good to know that that technique worked for you, too.  I think that it is also good for those who land on this page in the future, so they get to see what eventually helped or solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Matlab has a bundle of tools for this, see [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/multivariate-regression-2.html).

I believe that [`mvregress`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvregress.html) is the most rounded and mainstream tool.  See [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/specify-the-response-and-design-matrices.html) for setting up an analysis with it.

Also, [a comment in this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4517/regression-with-multiple-dependent-variables) may be useful for alternatives, if needed: it is possible to approach this via separate regression analyses, one for each response variable.